# song.play() returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined" for background music

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to get background music playing behind my game using p5.js.

However, I have tried every variation I can possibly think of, trying new Audio, not having preLoad, etc. And whatever I do I still get the

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined" on my backgroundMusic.play();

I have tried to follow what the `p5.js reference` says to do.

```
let backgroundMusic;

function preLoad(){
  backgroundMusic = loadSound("music.mp3");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 360);
  backgroundMusic.play();
  backgroundMusic.setVolume(10);

}
```

Comment: is the path for the musics correct.

Comment: I think so? I have tried to follow a CodeTrain video on youtube and I have almost the exact code but his works and mine does not. I have also tried to follow the p5.js library and it seems like this would work.

Comment: you need to call preLoad() method inside the setup to assign backGroundMusic. do this and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call preLoad() method inside the setup() to assign backGroundMusic.

```
let backgroundMusic;

function preLoad(){
  backgroundMusic = loadSound("music.mp3");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 360);
  preLoad(); //added
  backgroundMusic.play();
  backgroundMusic.setVolume(10);

}
```

Comment: Isn't [preload](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) a p5.js method which is executed by default before the setup function as per the docs?

Comment: @DTul, Yes that's what i am thinking, i never worked with the `p5` but i think the preload will get called by `p5` because the `setup` is called after the `preload` , and i don't see any examples calling the preload method in documentation...... correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## Here are few things i would like to add

You don't have to call the `preload` inside the `setup`, as mentioned in the above answer, because the `setup` is called by p5 after the `preload`, and if you will call the `preload` inside then p5 will again will call the `setup` and it will become a loop that will cause the stack to get overflow, you can read more about stack overflow here at [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4/#:%7E:text=A%20stack%20overflow%20occurs%20when,before%20throwing%20a%20stack%20error.)

## And here is what you should do to tackle this issue

**Add p5 sound and p5 both because the loadSound is inside the p5 sound.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Play the music</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            let mySound;
            function preload() {
                mySound = loadSound("./yourfile.mp3");
                // Todo : Add the path to your file above
            }

            function setup() {
                let cnv = createCanvas(100, 100);
                cnv.mousePressed(canvasPressed);
                background(220);
                text("tap here to play", 10, 20);
            }

            function canvasPressed() {
                mySound.play();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## [Run the Above Code](https://repl.it/@webcandy/p5-playsound#index.html)